# Вывод только последних

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет :)

Есть код:

```
<?
$tmp      = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE poluchatel='$user_email' or author='$user_email' ORDER BY id DESC", $db);
$messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp);

if (!empty($messages['id'])) {
    do {
        if ($messages['poluchatel'] == $user_email) {
            $author  = $messages['author'];
            $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT id, small_avatar, name, last_name FROM users WHERE email='$author'", $db);
            $myrow4  = mysql_fetch_array($result4);

            printf("
            <a href='private_messages_chat.php?other_user_id=%s'>
                <div class='dialog'>
                    <img class='small_90_avatar' width='90' height='90' alt='Автор' src='%s'>
                    <div class='avtor-bar'>
                        <div class='user-name'>
                            %s %s
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='message-fild'>
                        %s
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            ", $myrow4['id'], $myrow4['small_avatar'], $myrow4['last_name'], $myrow4['name'], $messages['text']);
        } else {
            $poluchatel = $messages['poluchatel'];
            $result5    = mysql_query("SELECT id, small_avatar, name, last_name FROM users WHERE email='$poluchatel'", $db);
            $myrow5     = mysql_fetch_array($result5);
            $author  = $messages['author'];
            $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT id, small_avatar, name, last_name FROM users WHERE email='$author'", $db);
            $myrow4  = mysql_fetch_array($result4);

            printf("
           <a href='private_messages_chat.php?other_user_id=%s'>
                <div class='dialog'>
                    <img class='small_90_avatar' width='90' height='90' alt='Автор' src='%s'>
                    <div class='avtor-bar'>
                        <div class='user-name'>
                            %s %s
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img class='small_63_avatar' width='63' height='63' alt='Автор' src='%s'>
                    <div class='message-fild-small'>
                        %s
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            ", $myrow5['id'], $myrow5['small_avatar'], $myrow5['last_name'], $myrow5['name'], $myrow4['small_avatar'], $messages['text']);
        }
    } while ($messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp));
} else {
    echo "Сообщений нет";
}
```

Этот код выводит все сообщения, а мне нужно, чтобы выводил только последние. Например, как ссылка на диалоги вконтакте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GROUP BY (здесь название столбца)
```

Группируйте, пробуйте всякие связки с GROUP BY, много вариаций.

Comment: Сам писал систему диалогов, нужно было подобное - реализовал через группировку (GROUP BY).

Самое легкое - сделать 2 запроса.

1 Запрос:
SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE poluchatel='$user_email' ORDER BY id DESC GROUP BY author

2 Запрос:
SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE author='$user_email' ORDER BY id DESC GROUP BY poluchatel

Далее думаешь понимаешь, что и как.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5
```

Сортируем по дате по убыванию и отбираем 5 последних.

Дата у вас же есть наверное?

Comment: Зачем ему 5? Ему 1 надо + id - как номер записи, что впринципи сортировка по id тоже вариант.

Comment: Дата конечно есть. Но почему 5 Их можетбыть и больше и меньше ? И вобщем не подходит ...

Comment: Ребята, сортировка не важна, с ней я сам разбирусь. Мне нужно, что бы отфильтровывалось по одному последниму варианту совпадения в базе,  где `poluchatel='$user_email' or author='$user_email'`. Например: нашло в таблице строку `poluchatel='$user_email' author='1'` (предположим) потом нашло ещё штук сорок строк, удовлетворяющих этому условию, но мне вывело только последние, одно. Потом нашло в таблице строку `poluchatel='$user_email' author='2'` пJтом нашло ещё 30 строк, удовлетворяющих этому условию, но мне вывело только последние, одно. И так далие. Понятно?

Comment: Можно сделать 2 отдельных запроса по получатедю и отправителю. Или там еще какие-то моменты?

Comment: Ну, сделаю я их по отдельности, а дальше-то что?

Comment: Можете конкретно написать требование. Потому что я не очень понимаю в чем проблема. Вам нужно выводить последнее письмо (LIMIT + ORDER). Вам нужно выводить последнее письмо как у отправителя, так и у получателя (можно разбить на 2 запроса). В чем трабла?

Comment: Отпровителей и получателей бесконечно много ...

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, если правильно понял в запросе укажите в конце limit 1.

```
$tmp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE poluchatel='$user_email' or author='$user_email' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", $db);
```

Comment: Нет, к сожаленью не правильно вы поняли.
Предположим в базе данных Id author poluchatel ... есть сообщения (предположим их дохрена) в данном коде я извлекаю вё сообщения где poluchatel='$user_email' or author='$user_email' , нужно не все а поодному последнему , где poluchatel='$user_email' or author='$user_email'.